# colorbox and text placement

Tags: horizontal-alignment, color

I was playing up with `\colorbox` for my resume and really loved the way I can create styling for the document.

Anyway I was trying to center align the text but failed to achieve it using the `\centering` command and if I use `\begin{center}` to allign the text, `\colorbox` width increase two fold which I don't want.

```
\newcommand \reshead [1]{\par \noindent \colorbox{black}{\begin{minipage} 
{\textwidth}{\color{white} \centering \bfseries {#1}} \hfill \end{minipage}}}
```

Apart from this issue, I wanted to my resume to look like this, the top line should be lesser in length compared to `\colorbox`

[image]

However with my code both are equal, is there a way I can stretch the `\colorbox` a bit more.? -

```
%% (c) Shashwat Pant
%% Resume - C.V of Shashwat Pant
%% September 17th 2012

\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
%\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
% \usepackage{charter}
% \usepackage{mathpazo}
%\usepackage{kpfonts}
%\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{color}
%\definecolor{mygrey}{gray}{0.95}
%\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand \reshead [1]{\par \noindent \colorbox{black}{\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}{  \color{white} \centering \bfseries {#1}} \hfill \end{minipage}}}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\bfseries {\huge {Shashwat Pant}} \\
\bfseries E-Mail - shashwat.pant@gmail.com ~ Voice -    
\hrule \hrule
 \end{center}

\noindent Seeking a challenging career to gain experience in rich evolving computing in the areas of :  
\begin{itemize} 
    \item 
    \item Parallel and Vector computing (Open CL)

\end{itemize}   


\reshead{Professional Profile}



\end{document}
```

With my code the output look like this

[image]

Is there a way to stretch the `colorbox` and underlying text a bit towards left so that are  not in same symmetry?

Comment: As an aside if you really want a space before the `:`, you should use `areas of~:` instead of `areas of :` so that the colon does not end up on its own line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option that you can use:

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fullpage
\usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{changepage}% http://ctan.org/pkg/changepage

\newcommand\reshead[1]{%
  \par\noindent%
  \colorbox{black}{\makebox[\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep][c]{\textcolor{white}{\bfseries #1}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{adjustwidth}{2em}{2em}
  \begin{center}
    \bfseries
    {\huge Shashwat Pant} \\
    E-Mail - shashwat.pant@gmail.com ~ Voice - \\
  \end{center}

  \noindent\hspace*{-1em}\rule{\dimexpr\linewidth+2em}{2pt}

  \noindent Seeking a challenging career to gain experience in rich evolving computing in the areas of :  
  \begin{itemize} 
    \item 
    \item Parallel and Vector computing (Open CL)
  \end{itemize}
\end{adjustwidth}

\bigskip

\reshead{Professional Profile}

\end{document}​
```

Some things I've changed:

- Instead of `\hrule\hrule`, use a specified rule width: `\rule{\dimexpr\linewidth-2em}{2pt}`. With the horizontal movement, this rule overhangs on both sides by `1em`;
- Added [`chngpage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/chngpage) which provides the `adjustwidth` environment for modifying the margins locally; and
- Used `\makebox` instead of `minipage` to specify the contents of your `\reshead`. Also updated the width to fix within the margins *exactly* (`\linewidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep`).

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't stretch the `\colorbox`, but reduce the top rule:

```
%% (c) Shashwat Pant
%% Resume - C.V of Shashwat Pant
%% September 17th 2012

\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
%\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
% \usepackage{charter}
% \usepackage{mathpazo}
%\usepackage{kpfonts}
%\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{color}
%\definecolor{mygrey}{gray}{0.95}
%\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\reshead[1]{%
  \par\noindent
  \colorbox{black}{%
    \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}
    \color{white}\centering\bfseries#1
    \end{minipage}%
  }%
}


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\bfseries
{\huge Shashwat Pant} \\[1ex]
E-Mail - shashwat.pant@gmail.com ~ Voice -

% Here I reduce the rule by 1in on both sides (adjust to suit)
% The rule thickness is 1pt; it's 2pt from the bottom of the text above it
\nointerlineskip
\moveright 1in \vbox{\hsize=\dimexpr\hsize - 2in \relax
  \vskip 2pt % separation from the text above
  \hrule width \hsize height 1pt % rule thickness
}
\end{center}


\noindent Seeking a challenging career to gain experience 
in rich evolving computing in the areas of:  
\begin{itemize} 
    \item \LaTeX
    \item Parallel and Vector computing (Open CL)

\end{itemize}   


\reshead{Professional Profile}



\end{document}
```

You have to reduce a bit the width of the `minipage`, otherwise the `\colorbox` would be too wide and overflow on the right: this is the purpose of

```
\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax
```

[image]

The `\moveright` trick is a low level one, but once in a while it comes handy. :)